# Rails change primary id to 64 bit bigint

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using rails and the mysql2 adapter. I want to change all primary ids and foreign keys to be 64 bit integers instead of the default 32 bit as they are right now for my production database.

Is this possible on the fly or do I have to drop the database, change the structure and import the data again?

If there is a way to do it without dropping the database, even if it's a hack, it would be great to know.

Comment: Any alteration on a database at scale will result in down-time during the conversion. For tables that need 64-bit integers, which presumably have hundreds of millions of records in them, that conversion can take a very, very long time. You'll need to run tests to see how much this will impact your uptime.

Comment: @tadman Thank you, we'll have a fallback database during the conversion process and synchronize all the new data back before switching back to the main database.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While ActiveRecord does not support this, you are able to do it using `execute`

```
class UpdateUserIdLimit < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    # PostgreSQL
    execute('ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN id SET DATA TYPE BIGINT')
    # MySQL
    execute('ALTER TABLE users MODIFY COLUMN id BIGINT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT')
  end

  def down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

For new tables you should be able to simply do

```
def change
  create_table :users, id: false do |t|
    t.int :id, limit: 8, primary_key: true
    t.string :first_name
    t.string :last_name
  end
end
```

Also starting with Rails 5.1 primary keys will be `BIGINT` by default.

Comment: Will `id` still have the auto-increment option if I do it like that?

Comment: Isn't there a way of doing this with `change_column`?

Comment: Nope, doesn't look like it.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this soon.

Comment: If this is going to be used a lot, might be worth making a simple wrapper that does it reliably rather than depending on a lot of raw SQL, something like `change_id_column_type`. Interesting note about Rails 5.1 as well.

Answer (score 18):

Rails 5.1 already added a `bigint` type for migrations, you can do this:

```
change_column :users, :id, :bigint
```

Source:
http://www.mccartie.com/2016/12/05/rails-5.1.html

Comment: The real problem is how to change all associated foreign keys to `bigint` as well (the constraints themselves).

Comment: You'll need to drop existing constraints, change column type and then add the constraint again.

Comment: This is from the future, but I think at least Rails 4.2 also had `:bigint` defined, and I was able to convert without having to do anything to the foreign key constraints (drop and re-add). Not sure why that is.

Comment: I tried this and it fails with `Mysql2::Error: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value`

Comment: Please note that forgetting `autoincrement: true` option leads to unexpected errors

Comment: NOTE, the default is `bigint` but unfortunately, it is `signed` instead of `unsigned`. And it's not as easy to override the default like before Rails 5.1. If you want `unsigned bigint` to be the default, check out this Github issue and show your support: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/40967

Comment: You'll need to add `auto_increment: true` to prevent `Mysql2::Error: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value`. This will fix that for Rails 5. Otherwise the MySQL `Extra` data for that column will be `None`